# Split several Unix files into multiple files based on first column

Tags: linux

I have several files (*data.txt) and I am trying to split each of them into multiple files based on the content of column 1. I have managed to split them but I do not know how to name the output files with both `$filename` and column 1($1) using `print`. At the moment print in the following command gives me `$1 ".txt"`, so for example: ENSG00000108094.txt, ENSG00000115232.txt instead of file1_ENSG00000108094.txt, file1_ENSG00000115232.txt which is not suitable as I need to have separate outputs for each input file.
Here it is my command and I am not sure where I should use `"$b"` to get the expected outcome.

```
for filename in *_data.txt
 do
    b=${filename%%_data.txt}
cat $filename | awk 'NR==1 {header = $0; next}!header_printed[$1]++ {print header > $1".txt"}{print > $1".txt"}'
done
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you get rid of the [uuoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) and pass the filename to awk directly, you could derive `b` from the internal `FILENAME` variable. For only "several" files you could likely omit the loop and pass all the `*_data.txt` to a single invocation of awk and use `FNR==1` in place of `NR==1` to set the header and new filename - or in GNU awk, use the special `BEGINFILE` rule.

Comment: @steeldriver. Thank you for your suggestion, but I do not fully understand your description. Could you please write the code you propose above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to pass a shell variable into an awk program:

1. using the `-v` command line option:

   ```
   awk -v b=${filename%data.txt} '... {print > (b $1 ".txt")}'
   ```
2. pass the value as an ordinary argument after the awk program

   ```
   awk '... {print > (b $1 ".txt")}' b=${filename%data.txt}
   ```
3. pass the value in the *environment* and access it within awk via the intenal `ENVIRON` array

   ```
   b=${filename%data.txt} awk '... {print > (ENVIRON["b"] $1 ".txt")}'
   ```

However, if you only have "several" files it might make sense to omit the shell loop altogether, and pass all the globbed files directly to awk, where you may derive the output file prefix from the `FILENAME` internal variable, ex.:

```
awk '
  FNR==1 {header = $0; b = FILENAME; sub(/data.txt$/,"",b); next}
  !header_printed[b $1]++ {print header > (b $1 ".txt")}
  {print > (b $1 ".txt")}
' *_data.txt
```

(you could also use `split` or `substr` to remove the `data.txt` suffix - I used regex `sub` because it is closest to the `${filename%data.txt}` shell expansion).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have accepted your answer!